# Calculating the integral $\int_{0}^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{\cos(x^2/ \pi)}{\sinh x}dx$ where s is a complex variable and $1<Re(s)$.

Tags: integration, number-theory, improper-integrals, mellin-transform

I want to evaluate the above integral, I know this is related to Mellin transform. But I am unable to calculate the integral using the definitions of integral or any other method. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the integrand behaves like $x^{s - 2}$ near $x=0$. Hence, you need $\Re s>1$.

Comment: Yeah, then how shall I proceed further after considering the domain Re(s)>1?

Comment: This is unlikely to be expressible in terms of known special functions. What's the original problem?

Comment: I am actually reading a research paper on Riemann zeta function and this integral is involved in some step. There is no further calculation or steps beyond this, so I wanted to know what this integral turns out to be.

Comment: @Kashif  Let your integral be $f(s)$, I remember there is a functional equation relating $f(s)$ and $f(1-s)$, but it does not give any explicit expression for $f(s)$ itself.

Comment: @pisco Yes, after thinking about the problem for this long, I don't think I actually need the explicit expression. Can you please help me with the functional equation?

Comment: @pisco The other integral required is $\int_{0}^\infty x^{-s} \frac{\cos (x^2/ \pi)}{\sinh x}$. So your idea will work here I guess as this integral is nothing but $f(1-s)$ then.

Comment: @Kashif  What's the paper you encounter the integral?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111164/discussion-between-kashif-and-pisco).

Comment: @Kashif  A [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819585) was asked several days ago, I provide a proof of the functional equation there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, however, it does not lead to a nice closed form solution. Under the conditions defined above, let $I_{s}$ be defined as:

\begin{equation}
I_{s}=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}\cos\left(x^{2}/\pi\right)}{\sinh(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Note that for all $x$:

\begin{equation}
\cos\left(\frac{x^{2}}{\pi}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\pi^{-2k}x^{4k}}{(2k)!}
\end{equation}

Plugging this last expression in $I_{s}$:

\begin{equation}
I_{s}=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{\sinh(x)}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\pi^{-2k}x^{4k}}{(2k)!}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{s}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\pi^{-2k}}{(2k)!}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1+4k}}{\sinh(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Introducing the exponential definition of $\sinh(x)$:

\begin{equation}
I_{s}=2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\pi^{-2k}}{(2k)!}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1+4k}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{s}=2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\pi^{-2k}}{(2k)!}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1+4k}e^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Let's deal with the integral first and set it equal to $I$:

\begin{equation}
I=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1+4k}e^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

In the interval $[0,\infty)$, it holds that: $0\leq e^{-2x}\leq1$, so we can use the geometric series for $e^{-2x}$:

\begin{equation}
I=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} x^{s-1+4k}e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e^{-2nx}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} x^{s-1+4k}e^{-x(1+2n)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

With the substitution $z=x(1+2n)$, you get that:

\begin{equation}
I=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+2n)^{s+4k}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} z^{(s+4k)-1}e^{-z}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}

The last integral evaluates to $\Gamma(s+4k)$, thus:

\begin{equation}
I=\Gamma(s+4k)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+2n)^{s+4k}}
\end{equation}

It is known that for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>1$, the following holds:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+2n)^{z}}=(1-2^{-z})\zeta(z)
\end{equation}

Thus:

\begin{equation}
I=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1+4k}e^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(s+4k)(1-2^{-(s+4k)})\zeta(s+4k)
\end{equation}

Getting back to our $I_{s}$ and plugging this in, you can conclude that:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}\cos\left(x^{2}/\pi\right)}{\sinh(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\pi^{-2k}\Gamma(s+4k)(1-2^{-(s+4k)})\zeta(s+4k)}{(2k)!}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that your series diverges for any $s$ because of $\Gamma(s+4k)$ in the numerator. Plugging in the power expansion of $\cos(x^2/\pi)$ is a fatal move here.

Comment: If one expands $1/\sinh x$ in odd powers of $e^{-x}$, the integral can be written as a (slowly) convergent series in terms of parabolic cylinder functions. I do not think, however, that such a series is more useful than the original form.